# CSRF verification fails when uploading file in admin inline

Tags: django, django-admin

In django 2.2.12 I have a simple TabularInline, where I add comments to my main model. As soon as I try to add a file to my comment I get a CSRF error.

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Comment(BaseModel):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True,related_name = "comments")
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='docs/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Admin.py

```
class CommTab(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    extra = 0


class MatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CommTab,)
```

If I save it without a file there is no problem. The source code of the page seems to be fine (csrf token is in the form).

Answer (score 0):

I actually had resolved this issue before in another project but forgotten about it - for some reason I needed to increase the FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE and then it works.